# asp the name 'lblTest' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the error

> "the name 'lblTest' does not exist in the current context"

which is really bugging me out.

ASPX:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTest" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="blabal"></asp:Label>
```

I've placed it in between the content-tags.

code behind:

```
protected void showResend()
{
    lblTest.Visible = true;
}
```

What I've tried:

- Checked spelling
- Checked that it's the correct namespace
- Checked that the ASPX and the code-behind pages are propperly linked
- Made sure that it's `runat="server"`
- Deleted the designer.cs page and re-generated it
- Cleared visual studio cache

And those are all the suggested sollutions I've found on google and SO. Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTest1" Visible="false" runat="server" Text="blabal"></asp:Label>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlDataList" runat="server" Visible="false" cssclass="draggable"></asp:Panel>

protected void showResend()
{
    //lblTest1.Visible = true;    //Doesn't work
    pnlDataList.Visible = true;   //works fine
}
```

Comment: Does your page contain more controls? Do you have same problems with other controls?

Comment: @johan: did u check the Inherits in aspx page.

Comment: @labilbe Yes, it does. And no, I don't have the same problem.

Comment: @Raj No, what do you mean? What should I check?

Comment: Please show the entire ASPX and C# file.

Comment: Why don't you create a new label (like id="lblTest1"), delete the problematic one and rename lblTest1 to lblTest?

Comment: Have you tried removing the text in the `ID` tag and writing it again? If you're using Visual Studio, it sometimes bugs out like that.

Comment: @CodeCaster the ASPX and C# files are huge (I'm working on old code). Any particular sections you are interested in? Is for example the "page load" relevant?

Comment: @labilbe Tried it, didn't work. Also tried Loyalars suggestion. didn't work

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson Does the `lblTest` have any parent controls that are databound, like a `Repeater` or a  `ListView`?

Comment: @Loyalar nope. I'll add some code showing why this is so strange :P

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson Sounds good. If you can add at least some of the parent controls of the `lblTest`, that would help immensely.

Comment: @Loyalar currently, the only parent is a div without any particular properties except for styling

Comment: @JohanHjalmarsson Is the `pnlDataList` in the edited part of your question a sibling (in the DOM) of the `lblTest`?

Comment: @Loyalar hmm, no. If I use "inspect element" in firefox it appears that the label is a child of the panel... even though the label is placed before the panel begins :S

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82462/discussion-between-loyalar-and-johan-hjalmarsson).

Comment: "Deleted the designer.cs page and re-generated it" and does it contain the declaration of `lblTest` now?

Comment: @JonHanna lblTest is right there in the designer page, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is most likely that the control is a child of a parent that blocks the direct access to the control, likely because it is a databound control (like a `Repeater` or a `Listview`).

Try moving the label to a line as far up in the DOM tree as possible, like at the start of an `asp:Content` control. This will ensure that it has no databound parents, and you should be able to access the control.